# Apache Spark Column has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index with PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

Whenever I attempt to transfer data to Azure SQLDW from Apache Spark using PySpark on Apache Spark I get the following error:

```
Column 'cd_created_date' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index
```

My schema is as follows:

```
root
 |-- extraction_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ce_case_data_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_last_modified: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_jurisdiction: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_latest_state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_reference: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_security_classification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_last_state_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
```

The failure starts with field 'cd_created_date', but I'm sure I will also get the error with 'cd_last_state_modified_date'.

My guess is that I will need to change schema of those fields to fix the problem, but I'm not sure.
Any thoughts?

Comment: It's nvarchar(max), varchar(max) and varbinary(max) that cannot participate in a columnstore index.  I can't think why you'd have a date column marked as one of these - it's crazy!

Comment: @wBob, thanks for your comments. For you information, that is how the schema was imported. I didn't choose the format